# The Projection of Two Vectors

Tags: vectors, projection

> Problem: 
> For vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, we have $ \mathbf{p} = \text{proj}_{\mathbf{v}}(\mathbf{u})$. If $\|\mathbf{u}\| = 11$ and $\|\mathbf{p}\| = 6$, find $\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{u}$.

I don't understand how to do this problem because, to me, it seems like there isn't enough information, but I know that there is. I know that any vector and its projection either form the hypotenuse and a leg of a right triangle, or that they are equal. So I can figure out the cosine of the angle between $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{p}$. But, I don't know how exactly I would do that? Sorry, I'm just really confused. Any advice? Below is what one of my friends told me to do, but I don't get it.

$$ \mathbf{p} = \text{proj}_{\mathbf{v}}(\mathbf{u}) = \| \mathbf{u} \cos(\theta) \| \, \hat{v}$$

or that

$$\begin{align}
\|\mathbf{p}\| &= \|\mathbf{u}\|\cos(\theta) \\
\cos(\theta) &= \frac{\|\mathbf{p}\|}{\|\mathbf{u}\|}
\end{align}$$

Comment: In the future, please enter the problem that you’re trying to solve as text instead of pasting a picture of it. Without that image, your question is nigh incomprehensible, thus inaccessible to people who depend on screen readers. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor show up in summaries. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the formula for vector projection is $$\mathrm{proj}_{\mathbf{v}}(\mathbf{u}) =\mathbf{p}=\left(\frac{\mathbf{u} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf{v}}{\| \mathbf{v} \| ^{2}}\right)\mathbf{v}$$
Supposing $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, this can be written as $$\mathbf{p}=\left(\frac{\Vert \mathbf{u}\Vert \Vert \mathbf{v}\Vert \cos( \theta )}{\| \mathbf{v} \| ^{2}}\right)\mathbf{v}=\left(\frac{\Vert \mathbf{u}\Vert \cos( \theta )}{\| \mathbf{v} \| }\right)\mathbf{v}$$

Therefore $$\Vert \mathbf{p}\Vert =\left(\frac{\Vert \mathbf{u}\Vert \cos( \theta )}{\| \mathbf{v} \| }\right)\Vert \mathbf{v}\Vert =\Vert \mathbf{u}\Vert \cos( \theta )$$
Now, since $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathrm{proj}_{\mathbf{v}}(\mathbf{u})$ point in the same direction, the angle between $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ is also $\theta$, therefore $$\mathbf{u} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf{p} =\Vert \mathbf{u}\Vert \Vert \mathbf{p}\Vert \cos( \theta ) =\Vert \mathbf{p}\Vert ^{2} .$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the length of the projection of $u$ on $v$ is $6,$ and the length of $u$ is $11,$ then if the angle between $u$ and its protection $p$ on $v$ is $\phi,$ then we must have $$6=11\cos\phi.$$

Now since $p\cdot u=|p||u|\cos\phi, $ and we know $|p|=6,\,|u|=11$ and $\cos\phi=6/11,$ can you now finish it off?