# Notation for tensors of rank 3 and higher

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, tensors

A tensor of rank 2 is often denoted $\bar{\bar{D}}$. What is the notation for higher-ranked tensors?

Comment: I think the best is to just say in words: $T$ is a tensor of type $(r,s)$ over the vector space $V$. Or in symbols, $T \in T^r_s(V)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rank 2 tensor is a matrix. In my own (handwritten) work, I denote a vector with a single underline ($\underline{v}$), a  matrix with a double underline ($\underline{\underline{M}}$) and a tensor (rank 3 or higher) with a rectangle underneath [EDIT:  have been alerted that this is indeed possible and looks like this: $\underset{\square}T$]  or perhaps bold unitalicized ($\mathit{\mathbf{T}}$).
This is assuming I need to reference all three kinds of objects at once. However, if I am only talking about matrices, or only talking about vectors, or only talking abou tensors, I might simply use boldface, like in my answer to [this post about vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3643771/the-projection-of-two-vectors/3643794#3643794) or [this post about matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3680337/finding-a-good-notation-for-matrices-with-non-negative-determinant/3680587#3680587). In short, there is no universally accepted standard, but you should do your best to make it clear.

Comment: $\underset{\square}{T}$ is
    \underset{\square}{T}

Comment: Nice find! I didn't know you could do this.